# CKEditor 5 model conversion with Promise

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am creating a CKEditor 5 plugin which must display a list based on the result of a REST call. 
I registered my schema item with:

```
editor.model.schema.register('myItem', {
  allowIn: '$root',
  isBlock: true,
  isObject: true
});
```

Then added the converters:

```
editor.conversion.for('upcast').add(upcastElementToElement({
  view: {
    name: 'div',
    classes: 'myItem'
  },
  model: 'myItem'
}));
editor.conversion.for('dataDowncast').add(downcastElementToElement({
  model: 'myItem',
  view: (modelElement, viewWriter) => {
    return getContent(modelElement, viewWriter);
  }
}));
editor.conversion.for('editingDowncast').add(downcastElementToElement({
  model: 'myItem',
  view: (modelElement, viewWriter) => {
    const div = getContent(editor.model, viewWriter);

    return toWidget( div, viewWriter, { label: 'widget label' } );
  }
}));
```

My getContent method is responsible for fetching data with the REST call. My issue is that if I use *axios* or *fetch* to get the data, it returns a Promise and I don't know how to pass the result to the 'view' attribute of the object passed to downcastElementToElement method. This 'view' attribute expects a function which returns the object to display.
Is there a way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKEditor 5 doesn't support async conversion. It'd complicate the conversion and it would provide bad experience as the editor would need to be locked during the fetching. I'd suggest creating a sync conversion and then after the fetching replace it with your specific element from DB.

Comment: An example of such a feature is the image upload. A placeholder is shown until the image is uploaded so a URL to it is available. The conversion is synchronous (though it converts to a placeholder if the source is not available yet). Asynchronousity is handled separately.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the suggestion and the example.